# How to solve the following inequality for x? $\frac{x^5+2x}{x^2} > y $

Tags: inequality

This is what I have already tried:

$\frac{x^5+2x}{x^2} > y $

$\frac{x^5}{x^2} + \frac{2x}{x^2} > y $

${x^3} + \frac{2}{x} > y $

I am not sure where to go next or if those are the right steps to take.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: It behaves like a quartic. If you throw it to Wolfram Dev Platform, it even gives you the answers on one page. They're not exactly pretty, though. Here I'm talking about the associated equation $\dfrac{x^5+2x}{x^2}=y.$ You're probably going to get a better answer if you plot the function $y=\dfrac{x^5+2x}{x^2}$ and go from there.